# Jquery .append() ¿Por qué no se ve el contenido en Firefox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, chrome

Tengo una aplicación web de libros (tienda) que hace una petición AJAX a un server que devuelve un JSON con codigo html de los libros (foto, titulo y breve descripción)
Al recibir la respuesta, hago un .append() del html que me devuelve JSON en un elemento $("#libros_container").

En Chrome, se ve perfectamente sin embargo en Firefox, queda el hueco que deberían ocupar los libros en blanco, es decir, si se tuvieran que mostrar 3 libros, quedaría el hueco en blanco correspondiente a 3 libros. Cuando hago una peticion que me devuelve 20 libros, el hueco en blanco que queda es mucho más grande.

Os muestro unas capturas:

[image: 2 Resultados Chrome]

[image: 2 Resultados Firefox]

La primera es de Chrome, donde se muestran 2 resultados (si os fijáis abajo pone "Mostrando del 1 al 2 de 2")

La segunda es de Firefox y tambíen pone "Mostrando del 1 al 2 de 2"

Cuando hay 10 resultados, el hueco en blanco es más grande. Lo que me da a pensar que se está aplicando el append, pero no se visualiza.

La consola de Firefox no da ningún error y la respuesta AJAX es la esperada ("Si no, no funcionaría tampoco en Chrome").

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Tendrías que ver que propiedades **CSS** tiene el elemento `#libros_container` porque tiene pinta de que existe una regla específica para Firefox que está podiendo algo como `visibility: hidden` a ese elemento. Sin ver tu código me temo que poco más puedo aventurar.

Comment: Por favor, comparte código, para así intentar identificar el problema y poder buscar una solución. Gracias

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Vale tengo la solución:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 mb-15">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Librería</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=site_url('destacados')?>">Destacados</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=site_url('novedades')?>">Novedades</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"> 
        <h3 class="no-margin">Librería</h3>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="<?= $configuracion_layout_tienda['page_container'];?>" id="libros_container"></div>
</div>
```

Resulta que tenía que añadir un div.clearfix antes del #libros_container. Sinceramente, siempre que algo con bootstrap no se visualiza y no tiene sentido, lo arreglo con un clearfix. no sé por qué se me ha escapado esta vez, supongo que por que en Chrome se veía correctamente. Gracias de todas formas!

Codigo arreglado:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 mb-15">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Librería</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=site_url('destacados')?>">Destacados</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?=site_url('novedades')?>">Novedades</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12"> 
        <h3 class="no-margin">Librería</h3>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="<?= $configuracion_layout_tienda['page_container'];?>" id="libros_container"></div>
</div>
```